# Why would we still need to define our own function comparator

Tags: c++, stl

In some `std` library `template`'s parameter, one need to define his/her own function comparator `less(a, b)`, `more(a, b)` then `std::some_template<T, *, myComparator()>`, but why?

Comment: All most all have their defaults comparator.
Its all on programmer's intention

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't know what to call to that term that's why I just call it stl, sorry

Comment: @mr5 Did you mean "template"?

Comment: It's to allow a user-defined comparison for user-defined types.

Comment: @0x499602D2 but I can't see the point there, uhm its almost less() or more() only or equal()?

Comment: `std::some_template<T, *, myComparator()>` Can you work a little more on this? Like... provide a particular case of `some_template`, and some template arguments that are actually valid (`*` is not a valid template argument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the comparator is to allow sorting of objects in the sorted stl containers. You only need to provide your own comparator if the default one is inadequate for the object type that the container will hold.

For example if you were to make a std::set of the following `struct`, then you would need to write your own comparator.

```
struct Person
{
    std::string first_name, last_name, phone_number;
}
```

The default comparator knows how to compare numbers and strings, but it doesn't know how to compare Person objects. This is how one could write a custom comparator for sorting Person objects by last_name.

```
struct Person_Comparator
{
    bool operator()(const Person &a, const Person &b) const {
        return a.last_name < b.last_name;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example lets make a set with some different criterion

```
 int main()
 {  
    //By default set will use std::less<int>()
    //Lets  make a set based on no. of 1's in binary representation of elements

    set<int,mycomp> s; 
    for(auto i=1;i<20;i++) //Note :Duplicates 1's representation will be discarded
        s.insert(i);

    for(auto i:s)
        cout<<i<< " ";  //19 15 8 7 3 1
     return 0;
 }
```

And the corresponding comparator will be something like following:

```
struct mycomp
{
    bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b) const {
        auto count_bits = [](long n){
            unsigned int c;
            for (c = 0; n; c++) 
            n &= n - 1; 
            return c;
        };
          return count_bits(a) != count_bits(b);
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We still occasionally need to define our own function comparators in generic programming, but we don't always need to write it ourselves :) You can just use this online wizard [http://www.xochellis.org/genericdataordering/wizard.php] of mine, to create the strict-weak-ordering functors, or lambdas you need.

For instance in the case of the `Person_Comparator` example of a previous answer, you just need to fill three fields in the wizard form, like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehoMJ.png) shows.

For more details you can refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601039/Online-Generic-Data-Ordering-Wizard) as well:

Best regards,
Jim Xochellis